# How to expand a primal burst at paragon level?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

I'm remaking my Hunter in my home game for when we hit level 15. Paragon Multiclass Path, Druid. Human, took bonus at will power (Twin Strike), now swapping it out for the Druid power Grasping Tide. If you don't know or you forgot, area burst 1 within 10, Wisdom vs Fortitude, Hit: 1d6 + Wis mod damage, and until the end of your next turn, if the target tries to leave the area, you make a secondary attack as an *opportunity* action. Wisdom vs Reflex, you knock the target prone. Amazing at will control power, if they're melee, which my GM seems to prefer.

Now. Paragon Feat: Resounding Thunder; You can add 1 to the size of any blast or burst that has the thunder keyword. My GM seems to like to start with the monsters spread out, a burst 1 might not cut it. I can go first pretty reliably: +25 Init and roll twice. If I can hit a substantial number of the monsters with this thing before they act, it would make things a lot easier because we have only one melee with a really low Init and no leader.

But I would have to make the power Thunder somehow to use Resounding Thunder, and I can't figure that out. Unless there's some other way of expanding a Primal burst at this level? Enlarge Spell doesn't work, that's only for Wizards.

I have Clever Shot, one of the things it can do is slide a target 2, that helps but I would have to spend an action point to do both, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add the Thunder keyword is with an implement that does so. Unfortunately, this isn't possible unless there is a way you can get to using a bow as an implement. The best bet would be a staff enchanted to deal Thunder damage on all of it's attacks. Unfortunately, there isn't one.

However, if you're looking for an opener, I'd recommend grabbing a Druid encounter power for this. Call Lightning would be a nice one, and if you wanted to still keep that feat, it can create an area burst 2 that would be a pretty night effect (immediate damage and an area effect that penalizes movement and stacks some other penalties).

Comment: But this is a Druid power. I guess I didn't make that clear, sorry. Edited.

Comment: Neither, multiclass. Paragon Multiclassing Paragon Path. I took Novice Power, Acolyte Power, and Adept Power multiclass feats and took the path. http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Paragon_multiclassing EDIT This was in response to Eagle, he asked me if I was Hybrid or Half-Elf but his question seems to have disappeared somehow!

Comment: Gotcha, much more difficult to add thunder to an implement power...Yeah I deleted my comment because I re-read the question. Just a heads up, some paragraph breaks would make this *way* more readable

Comment: @Admiralshlork made a hefty update

Comment: You can use a bow as an implement. If you are a Sehanine worshipper, you can either use a Moonbow or take the Moonbow Dedicate feat. Either way, it only works as an implement for arcane or divine powers though. The only primal weaplements I could find were specifically for Shamans.

Comment: @Admiralshlork you can use a staff enchanted as a weapon, but again, thunder is a tough damage type :(.

Comment: Are you able to take/change your character theme?